# RadioButtons acting strange Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, radio-button, components

I'm trying to create a custom component that groups some Radio Button this way

```
<group>
  <radio></radio>
  <radio></radio>
  <radio></radio>
</group
```

Inside of the  component I add dynamically a name for the inputs, so they all have the same name and change the selected one when I click on another.

It works good if I only have one component, if i have more than one, it extends the values like if it were only a group of RadioButtons with only one name.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ContentChildren, ElementRef, Input, NgModule, QueryList} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {ControlValueComponent} from "../shared/ControlValueComponent";
import {SysSharedModule} from "../shared/SysSharedModule";

@Component({
  selector: 'sys-radio-button',
  styleUrls: ['sysRadioButton.css', '../shared/sys.css'],
  providers: ControlValueComponent.providerValueAcessor(SysRadioButton),
  template: `    
      <input type="radio" id="rb{{randomId}}" [value]="val" [(ngModel)]="value">
      <label for="rb{{randomId}}">{{label}}</label>
  `
})

export class SysRadioButton extends ControlValueComponent {

  constructor (public elem: ElementRef) {
    super();
  }

  @Input() groupName = 'radiobutton';
  @Input() val: any;
  @Input() label: string;
  randomId = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 10000 + 1)) + 1) * -1;

}

@Component({
  selector: 'sys-radio-group',
  styleUrls: ['sysRadioButton.css', '../shared/sys.css'],
  providers: ControlValueComponent.providerValueAcessor(SysRadioGroup),
  template: `    
    <div class="t{{tam}}">
      <label class="header">{{header}}</label> 
      <div class="radioButtonContainer"></div> 
    </div>
  `
})

export class SysRadioGroup extends ControlValueComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() header: string;
  @Input() tam = '3-of-10';
  @ContentChildren(SysRadioButton) radioButtons: QueryList<SysRadioButton>;

  constructor (public elem: ElementRef) {
    super();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.addNameToInputs();
  }

  addNameToInputs() {
    const container = this.elem.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('radioButtonContainer')[0];
    this.radioButtons.forEach(item => {
      const input = item.elem.nativeElement;
      input.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].name = this.name;
      container.appendChild(input);
    });
  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SysSharedModule],
  declarations: [SysRadioButton, SysRadioGroup],
  exports: [SysRadioButton, SysRadioGroup]
})

export class SysRadioButtonModule {

}
```

And i use it like this:

```
<sys-radio-group header="Select your destiny" name="name1">
  <sys-radio-button val="hola1" label="Label 1"></sys-radio-button>
  <sys-radio-button val="hola2" label="Label 2"></sys-radio-button>
  <sys-radio-button val="hola3" label="Label 3"></sys-radio-button>
  <sys-radio-button val="hola4" label="Label 4"></sys-radio-button>
</sys-radio-group>
<sys-radio-group header="Select your destiny" name="name2">
  <sys-radio-button val="hola1" label="Label 1"></sys-radio-button>
  <sys-radio-button val="hola2" label="Label 2"></sys-radio-button>
  <sys-radio-button val="hola3" label="Label 3"></sys-radio-button>
  <sys-radio-button val="hola4" label="Label 4"></sys-radio-button> 
</sys-radio-group>
```

Here are some images of how it works

This is how it is when i don't click on anything
[image]

and this is how it looks when i click on one with the same value but a different name
[image]

If i check the elements in the chrome's console, i can see how the name's are different, so i don't understand why this is happening

**EDIT**

The ControlValueComponent class that extends the main classes,is just the one for the custom form. This is the code:

```
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from "@angular/forms";
import {forwardRef, Input} from "@angular/core";

export class ControlValueComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() disabled: boolean;

  innerValue: any = '';

  static providerValueAcessor( ref: any): any {
    return [
      { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => ref), multi: true }
    ];
  }

  onTouchedCallback: () => void = () => {};

  onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = () => {};

  constructor() {
  }

  get value(): any {
    return this.innerValue;
  }

  set value(v: any) {
    if (v !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = v;
      this.onChangeCallback(v);
    }
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = value;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

}
```

So here is where the "value" variable of the [(ngModel)] comes from

Comment: You mean that both 'Label3' are checked ?

Comment: Yep, both labels that has the same value get checked, is something to do with the ngModel but i cant fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change ngModel to :

```
 [(ngModel)]="val"
```